# Template tags vs get_template_part() vs functions.php

Tags: functions, get-template-part, template-tags

When to use template tags and when to use `get_template_part()` and when to use `function.php`? I am confused at them.

For example, if I want to show related portfolios under single portfolio, I can create a template tag named `show_related_portfolios()`.

In contrast, I can create a file named `content-related-portfolios.php`, and use it like `get_template_part( 'content', 'related-portfolios' )`.

Or I can create a function which fetches related portfolios in `functions.php`.

Is there any best practices for using them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A template tag is just a function, so I can't understand the difference from a function in `functions.php` and a template tag.

So the choiches are 2: function VS file.

The right choice depend case by case, and all things **@shazzad** pointed found me agree.

I prefer use file and `get_template_part` when the code need to contain a lot of html, because I don't like having functions that open and close php tags or with large echo of html output.

In short I prefer file when the needed feature is all about presentation and prefer function when I need some computational work.

Sometimes I use both, e.g.:

```
if ( ! function_exists('show_related_portfolios') ) {

    function show_related_portfolios( $someargs = array() ) {
      $defaults = array( ... );
      $args = wp_parse_args( $someargs, $defaults );
      $related_q = new WP_query();
      if ( $related_q->have_posts() ) {
        while( $related_q->have_posts() ) { $related_q->the_post();
          // template for singular related portfolio
          get_template_part( 'content', 'related-portfolio' ); 
        }
      }
      wp_reset_postdata(); 
    }

}
```

in this way I can make use of function arguments, move the great part of php inside a function and template can be just html for the most part.

Using function also allow to use the feature as shortcode with very little work.

Note the `if ( ! function_exists('show_related_portfolios') ) {` statement: this prevent error if the function is already defined and in addition allow child themes to override the function completely. In addition, thanks to the use of `get_template_part` child themes can easily override the display of the singular item.

Note that is just a case, the one you used as example, but is impossible a general rule of what is better.

Answer (score 2):

`get_template_part()` should be a correct choice. Because,

- If the template file is missing, it wont be triggering any error, just blank.
- Others/ or you can find the file by name for future edits
- Plugin can use the hook and change the file dynamically

Where, using custom function could -

- trigger error if it's missing somehow It would take some time to find
  out where the function was written, if needed to edit by someone else
- It can not be modified by other function/plugin if you haven't left
  any hook.

Advantage of using function

- You could setup arguments for the function, what will come up handy with useful usage. Ex: `function( 'Number of related posts', 'Order', 'excluding / inclusion any posts')` etc.
- Template part checks for file existence (`file_exists`), what takes some loading time, But functions loads much faster.

That's my opinion, others might have some better opinion.